# Mirror cloud storage accounts

Tags: dropbox, onedrive, google-drive, cloud-storage

Is there any service that lets you mirror i.e. Dropbox and Drive? Let's say I change something on Dropbox and it's automatically applied to Drive as well. Like some sort of RAID-concept for cloud storage?

Comment: I just sync the folders so they have the same content contained within them.  I don't worry about space because duplicating 5GB,10GB, or even 15GB is nothing to me.

Comment: @Ramhound You mean you assign i.e. Dropbox and Drive the same paths on your local system? And they don't screw up each other?

Comment: I use a program to sync the two folders, so they have the same content, this results in duplicated data which I am willing to accept.

Comment: @Ramhound  there is a big imbalance though between the amount of free space in google drive and the amount in dropbox. So syncing would be limited by the smaller of the two.   Do you use dropbox for more than the free 2GB? it looks like  to get beyond that requires either subscribing (to like 100GB) or getting other people on it by referrals gaining 500MB a time.

Comment: @Ramhound I did not say you were wrong. You obviously seem to have a good set up if you have equal space on dropbox onedrive and google drive. I was essentially asking you -how- by what method. I was inviting you to advise me on how it's done.

Comment: @barlop The method I describe can sync all or some of the contents.  The program is GoodSync it has jobs that run daily

Comment: @Ramhound ok, thanks, but to get dropbox past 2GB? Is that a monthly fee? yearly fee? or did it take loads of referrals? or some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following Ramhounds advice and using [Synkron](http://synkron.sourceforge.net/) to keep multiple folders synked. I guess it's the best solution at the time, even though it takes up a lot of my precious SSD-space. There is definitely a need for a hosted service that solves this!

Comment: why does it have to be ssd space(which you suggest is costly).  why not a usb spinning disk drive?

Comment: @barlop I don't wanna rely on having any USB-device connected...

Comment: And why not an internal SATA spinning disk drive? And are you paying to get more than 2GB dropbox?